# memory allocation of base variabels when derived object is created in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

where are member variables of base class stored when an object of derived class is created in c# ?

```
 using System;
 class A
 {
   public int i;
 }
 class B:A
 {
   public int j;
   static public void Main()
   {
       B b = new B();
   }
 }
```

Here when b object is created where is i variable stored in the heap ?does it store in the instance of the b itself or separately ?

Comment: First question => in the heap because of reference type. Seocnd question => one heap for b. Not separately. You see some part of the heap depending of the type of the variable.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you care where it is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a single object (on the heap), with *all* the fields declared in the type hierarchy. I believe it's implementation-specific what order they're stored in, but it wouldn't surprise me to see all the fields in the base class, followed by the fields declared in the derived class, etc. (That way the offset for the field for any given declared type would always be the same regardless of the execution-time type.)

So the memory layout *might* look something like:

- Object header / sync block
- Method table pointer
- Field `i`
- Field `j`

But to answer the most direct part of your question: all the values that make up the state of the object are stored together, regardless of which type each field is declared in.

Comment: Then how will we know that field i is of class A.

Comment: @NagasivaniSiddana: Because the object "knows" it's of type `B`, and that type "knows" it's derived from `A`. Note that the data in memory would just be the values of the fields - the name "i" wouldn't appear in the data, because that would be pointless (repeated for every object of the same type).

Comment: @JonSkeet Does this mean that in the case given above - there will be a single object created on heap and that object points to class A's field internally.

Comment: @HershikaSharma: I'm not sure what you mean by "that object points to class A's field internally" but only a single object is created, yes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant object of child class would hold reference to parent class fields.

Comment: @HershikaSharma: No, all the fields are just together - because there's just one object. The address for `j` may well be immediately after the address for `i`, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet okay.. Thank you